# Custom widget dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

If I do not click:

[image]

When I press the button in the red circle:

[image]

Hello, I want to ask. What widget can I use to get a design like this? When the red circle is pressed, another menu will appear and can be pressed to go to another menu. I tried using the dropdown button but it doesn't work as I want. I have also used ListTileTheme and ExpansionTile but it still doesn't work as I want. Anyone can share an opinion.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/73399921/10157127 answer your question, that will be wrapped in container with border

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's core dropdown widget works almost exactly like your example, and there is a widget that extends it even further. You should then be able to nest further menus if that's what you need it to do. [Flutter DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)